# Uber Eats が提供している API は日本の Uber Eats で利用できますか？

Tags: api

Uber Eats が提供している下記の API は日本の Uber Eats （ https://www.ubereats.com/jp ）で利用できますか？

https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/introduction

日本の Uber Eats （ https://www.ubereats.com/jp ）に掲載されるレストランやメニューの情報を上記の API で操作できればと考えています。（私がレストランを経営するわけではなく、日本の Uber Eats に出店を考えているレストランからシステム部分の相談を受けて質問をさせていただいています。）

Comment: その後こちらは何か解決されましたか。
知見あれば教えてください。

Comment: こんな事例があるようですが。[【導入事例】UberEats様 APIとAWSを活用したデータ連携](https://www.hands-lab.com/contents/c9599/), [スマレジ・Uber Eats LINKの利用方法](https://help.smaregi.jp/hc/ja/articles/360052091274), [（テスト公開）スマレジ・Uber Eats LINKの利用方法](https://smaregi-suppot.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/360008967214)

Comment: この投稿をした少しあとくらいに Uber Eats に問い合わせメールを送ったのですが、返事はありませんでした。。 POS システムとの連携の事例は多いようなのですが、どこから問い合わせたら良いかもよくいのか、現時点でもよくうわかっていません。。